# Android Activity Transition slide animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-transitions

I wanna make a transition from Activity A to activity B via onClickListener on Button(btn). But I want to make a transition that looks like a Activity B window is pushing the Activity A window in a slide-like motion. [image]

I tried making it with a this line of code, but I can't get it quite right.

My Activity class code:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_translate, R.anim.activity_close_scale);
```

open_translate:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<translate
    android:duration="800"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"></translate>
```

close_scale:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="800"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"></translate>
<alpha
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromAlpha="1"
    android:toAlpha="0.8"/>
```

Comment: Fix your open_translate xml to: android:fromXDelta="-100%". And in your close_scale: android:fromXDelta="0%" and android:toXDelta="100%"

Comment: thank you, I was brainstuck for a while, you helped me a lot :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is code for open_translate :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >
<translate android:duration="500" android:fromXDelta="100%"  android:toXDelta="0"/>
<alpha android:duration="500" android:fromAlpha="1.0"   android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

This is code for close_scale:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >
<translate android:duration="500" android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p"/>
<alpha android:duration="500" android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```